# Please help me to solve this problem.

Tags: linear-algebra

If $\alpha,\beta$, and $\gamma$ are roots of the equation $$x^3 - 2x^2 + 4x - 5 = 0\;,$$ form the equation whose roots are $\alpha/(\beta+\gamma)$, $\beta/(\alpha+\gamma)$, and $\gamma/(\alpha+\beta)$.

Comment: Can you share your thoughts on the problem, and what you understand about the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: For example, what is $\dfrac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma} \dfrac{\beta}{\alpha + \gamma} \dfrac{\gamma}{\alpha + \beta}$?  The denominator is a symmetric polynomial in $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, and  homogeneous of degree $3$, so it must be a linear combination 
of $\alpha \beta \gamma$, $(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)(\alpha \beta + \alpha \gamma + \beta \gamma)$, and $(\alpha + \beta + \gamma)^3$...

Answer (score 2):

Expand factored equation for given polynomial
\begin{align}(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)&=x^3 -x^2 (\alpha +\beta+\gamma) +x (\alpha  \beta + \alpha  \gamma +\beta  \gamma) -\alpha  \beta  \gamma\end{align}
Equating coefficients, $$\alpha +\beta+\gamma= 2\\\alpha  \beta + \alpha  \gamma +\beta  \gamma=4\\\alpha  \beta  \gamma=5$$

Now expand the factored equation for desired polynomial and use basic algebra
$$\left(x-\frac{α}{β+γ}\right)\left(x-\frac{β}{α+γ}\right)\left(x-\frac{γ}{α+β}\right)$$For example you can write the linear term as $$x \frac{(\alpha +\beta +\gamma )(\alpha \beta +\alpha \gamma +\beta \gamma )-3\alpha \beta \gamma}{(\alpha +\beta + \gamma )(\alpha  \beta + \alpha  \gamma +\beta  \gamma )-\alpha  \beta \gamma}$$
You can make the substitutions to find the correct values of the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Using Vieta's formula, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\frac21=2$

Let $y=\frac{\alpha}{\beta+\gamma}$

$\implies y(\beta+\gamma)=\alpha\implies y(2-\alpha)=\alpha\implies \alpha=\frac{2y}{1+y}$

As $\alpha$ is a root of given equation, putting the value of $\alpha,$

$$\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)^3-2\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)^2+4\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)-5=0$$

$$\implies (2y)^3-2(2y)^2(1+y)+4(2y)(1+y)^2-5(1+y)^3=0$$

On simplification, $\displaystyle 3y^3-7y^2-7y-5=0$

As the roots are symmetric wrt $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$; if we start with  $y=\frac{\beta}{\gamma+\alpha}$ or  $y=\frac{\gamma}{\alpha+\beta},$ we shall get the same cubic eqaution

Answer (score 0):

There are much nicer solutions, but with patience and a bit of brute force you needn’t know much more than the fact that

$$p(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)=x^3-2x^2+4x-5\;.$$

If you multiply out, collect terms, and equate coefficients, you’ll find that

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&\alpha+\beta+\gamma=2\\
&\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma=4\\
&\alpha\beta\gamma=5\;.
\end{align*}\right.\tag{1}$$

Since $\beta+\gamma=2-\alpha$, $\alpha+\gamma=2-\beta$, and $\alpha+\beta=2-\gamma$, you want the polynomial

$$\left(x-\frac{\alpha}{2-\alpha}\right)\left(x-\frac{\beta}{2-\beta}\right)\left(x-\frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}\right)\;;$$

its coefficients are

$$\begin{align*}
&1\;,\\\\
&-\left(\frac{\alpha}{2-\alpha}+\frac{\beta}{2-\beta}+\frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}\right)\;,\\\\
&\left(\frac{\alpha}{2-\alpha}\right)\left(\frac{\beta}{2-\beta}\right)+\left(\frac{\alpha}{2-\alpha}\right)\left(\frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}\right)+\left(\frac{\beta}{2-\beta}\right)\left(\frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}\right)\;,\text{ and }\\\\
&-\left(\frac{\alpha}{2-\alpha}\right)\left(\frac{\beta}{2-\beta}\right)\left(\frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Each of these can be computed with the aid of $(1)$ and a bit of algebra. For example,

$$\begin{align*}
&\left(\frac{\alpha}{2-\alpha}\right)\left(\frac{\beta}{2-\beta}\right)+\left(\frac{\alpha}{2-\alpha}\right)\left(\frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}\right)+\left(\frac{\beta}{2-\beta}\right)\left(\frac{\gamma}{2-\gamma}\right)\\\\
&\qquad=\frac{\alpha(2-\beta)(2-\gamma)+\beta(2-\alpha)(2-\gamma)+\gamma(2-\alpha)(2-\beta)}{(2-\alpha)(2-\beta)(2-\gamma)}\\\\
&\qquad=\frac{4(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)-4(\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma)+3\alpha\beta\gamma}{(2-\alpha)(2-\beta)(2-\gamma)}\\\\
&\qquad=\frac{8-16+15}{p(2)}\\\\
&\qquad=\frac73\;.
\end{align*}$$